¿Cómo se llama a una persona que es ignorante a propósito?
Según la RAE, "ignorante" significa:


Que ignora o desconoce algo.
Que carece de cultura o conocimientos.


¿Qué termino se puede utilizar para referirse a alguien que es ignorante porque no quiere conocer algo?

Palabras relacionadas: Desentenderse es fingir que se ignora algo. Mosquillón es una persona que finge ser ignorante (palabra antigua y poco usada).

El término que se suele utilizar para referirse a alguien que es ignorante porque no quiere conocer algo es “necio”. Un necio es una persona que se niega a aprender o aceptar información nueva, a pesar de que está disponible.
http://www.wordreference.com: Necio, necia (persona terca)(coloquial) stick-in-the-mud (pejorative) pigheaded person. Un necio se aferra a sus ideas por equivocadas que sean. (A stick-in-the-mud to stands by their ideas no matter how wrong they are.)
http://www.significados.com: El término "necio" se utiliza para describir a una persona que es terca, obstinada o testaruda. Alguien que persiste en llevar a cabo sus ideas o acciones sin prestar atención a consejos razonables o a las advertencias de otros. Del mismo modo, un individuo necio puede mantenerse firme en sus opiniones o decisiones incluso después de haber sido demostrado que están equivocados, lo que puede llevar a conflictos o malentendidos con los demás.
https://definición.de/necio: “No trates de hacerle entender algo a un necio que no está dispuesto a escucharte.”
https://quesignificado.com/necio/: La Real Academia define al necio como imprudente o falto de juicio, terco en lo que dice o hace. Pero ello no significa que ambas palabras (necio y terco) sean sinónimos, sino que hay entre ellas una clara interrelación. La terquedad y la necedad comúnmente son características de un mismo tipo de persona, ya que quien es necio muy probablemente defienda su posición con obstinación. Es muy probable que quien es tonto también sea necio y testarudo (de testa “cabeza”), y que defienda con obcecación sus dichos porque está impedido de razonar las cosas o darse cuenta de ellas.
